# How to Use Play Framework's SBT to download Maxmind Database

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, maxmind

I'm integrating the maxmind geoip database in my play 2.1.1 app and want to know if there's a way to use SBT to download the maxmind geocitylite.dat.gz file for local use (the added wrinkle is I'm on a shared ec2 instance with no persistent storage so I only have access to the java.io.tmpdir.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is nothing out of the box for Maxmind.

But you could try to implement your own [SBT task](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks), which can download the file for you.

Comment: thanks, that may be exactly what I needed - just trying to use SBT to do things other than build.

Comment: `IO.download(URL, File)` may be a good start to doing that.  It doesn't cache or check if the file was downloaded though.  See also http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/#sbt.IO$

Comment: @MarkHarrah yep, seems pretty neat :-)